# Adding "Send As" address in Gmail result in an SMTP DNS error

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I want to send mail from my Gmail box (me@gmail.com) that will appear as sent from my Google Apps address (me@example.com).

While setting up the "send as" address, I'm asked to enter my SMTP server, username and password.

I use smtp.example.com with my Google Apps user and password, and I get the following DNS error:

> Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
>     [Server response: DNS Error: Address resolution of smtp.example.com. failed: Domain name not found code(0) ]

I have MX records set up on my domain host, and they show on Google Apps admin console.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

One option that bypasse the problem is to use Gmail SMTP server for the "send as" option.

- You use `smtp.gmail.com` as server address
- Your gmail email address as username
- The password should be generated by Google as an app password, using the instructions in the link below. *It is not* your Gmail account password.

This method worked for me:
[Using Gmail SMTP server](http://ellisbenus.com/web-design-columbia-mo/workaround-using-gmail-alias-forwarded-email-addresses/)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but a reader _still_ will need to follow that link to get a key piece of information.